# CS1 project help C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make it so that when the user inputs a number 1-5 in the first cin it assigns the int workout to the workout name that was selected. Basically the assignment uses the workout, time, and person's weight to calculate how many calories they will burn from working out. I defined all of the variables as integers, is that correct?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //menu structure
    cout << " ________________________________\n";
    cout << "|  Welcome to My Fitness Center  |\n";
    cout << "|--------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|            MAIN MENU           |\n";
    cout << "|       1) Rowing Machine        |\n";
    cout << "|       2) Running               |\n";
    cout << "|       3) Weight lifting        |\n";
    cout << "|       4) Yoga                  |\n";
    cout << "|       5) END                   |\n";
    cout << "|________________________________|\n";
    cout << "Enter the workout that you wish to track, or END to exit: \n";
    //prompts user to choose which workout they are going to be doing
    cin >> workout;

   //**Right here is where I am having an issue. I am not sure how to make it so that when the user enters "1" into the console that it changes the value of 'workout' to Rowing Machine etc.**

    cout << "Enter your weight in pounds: \n";
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "Enter the number of minutes: \n";
    cin >> minutes;

    weightKG = weight/2.2;
    caloriesBurned = (minutes/60)*(met)*(weightKG)/2.2;
    cout << "The total calories burned for " << workout << " was " << caloriesBurned << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note: this project does not allow the use of functions

Comment: Are you asking how to `switch` the value used in your calculation based on the user's input into `workout`?

Comment: Make your question clear. For each option there should be a formula to get the output (based on inputs). Unless it is clear, no one can answer.

Comment: Read up (search the internet) for "c++ integer division".  You will lose precision if you divide integers by 2.2.

Comment: You need to declare all of your variables.  You can use integers, as in Fixed Point Notation, or use `double`.

Comment: Yes, I am asking how to switch the value used for the calculation from what the user puts in

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if` or `switch`, you can place your values into an array:

```
double met[5] = 
{
  /* 0 */ 0.0, // This slot not used.
  /* 1 */ 1.6, // the factor for using rowing maching.
  /* 2 */ 0.8, // The factor for running,
  // ...
};

double calories_burned = (minutes/60)*(met[selection])*(weightKG)/2.2;
```

You would need to use `if` for range checking and exiting out of the program.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but we haven't started learning arrays yet, so I am not allowed to use them. The main issue that I am having and have been stuck on is that when the user inputs a value like 1 in the main menu portion I don't know how to make the program identify that the 'workout' it is doing is using the rowing machine or running etc. There is plenty more I need to work on and just filled in the rest of it pretty much to give an idea where the program is going. I tried looking up examples of switches, but all of them just used the switch to tell the user something using cout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, I was able to make an if statement that fixed the issue